# Solving system of PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, partial-derivative

I am stuck on the following problem: Solve for $f(x,y)$, where:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = y$,

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{2}xy$

My original strategy was to integrate the first equation giving:

$\frac{y^2}{2} + g(x)$, where $g(x)$ is a constant function, and then differentiating this and setting it equal to the second equation giving:

$g'(x) = \frac{1}{2}xy$, which I integrate again to give:

$g(x) = \frac{1}{4}x^2y + h(y)$, giving:

$f(x,y) = \frac{y^2}{2} + \frac{1}{4}x^2y + h(y)$,

but, where do you go from here?
Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't carry the negative sign when differentiating wrt x, also the last step should contain an arbitrary constant

Comment: Triatticus - Hi. Thanks. I have updated it now. I don't know where one would go from here!

Comment: Are you sure about the values of $f_y$ and $f_x$? Something seems to be inconsistent.

Comment: You don't need a constant dependent on y you've already eliminated that choice from the start, after the last step the only constant necessary is independent of x and y so C. Your answer is correct if it just has a C at the end

Comment: $g $ depends only on $x $ by assumption, so when you integrate its derivative you are left with a constant rather than an arbitrary function of $y $. This constant persists; you need an additional condition beyond the pdes to identify it.

Comment: Notice that $g$ should depend on $x$ only. So $g'(x) = x y /2$ would be a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers! So, can this system of equations even be solved?

Comment: Since $\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y} \ne \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}$, there is no (reasonable) solution.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for all your answers, this is much clearer now.

Comment: Hey! did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in any strong sense, suppose your function $f$ is twice times continuously differentiable, you can use Schwarz's theorem, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^{2}f(x,y)}{\partial x\partial y}\equiv
\frac{\partial^{2}f(x,y)}{\partial y\partial x}
\end{equation}
the partial derivatives of second order commute,
and would end up with the condition  \begin{equation}\frac{1}{2}x\equiv 0\end{equation} which is impossible.
Notice, that your question is strongly related to the question if there exists a potential with gradient $(\tfrac{1}{2}xy,y)$ and then the condition I gave would be called the integrability condition...

Comment: Hello. Thank you. That is much clearer now!

Comment: Is it even possible to find the exact potential whose gradient is equal to an arbitrary function? Or are there any approximate methods? I am not an expert in this, but I would be very interested to know this.