# How to find the energy functional of a given PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, nonlinear-analysis

It is not hard to write down the Euler-Lagrange equation of a functional, but for a given PDE, how to prove the existence and uniqueness of its energy functional? And for a PDE that has an energy functional, is there a general method to find its energy functional? If not, there must have been some methods to find the energy functionals associated with PDEs of certain types, can anyone please tell me where I can find some references?

Comment: To determine a functional, multiplication by the solution to the equation and integrating by parts works fairly often i.e $$u_{t} = \Delta u \implies uu_{t} = u \Delta u \implies \frac{1}{2} \partial_{t} \int_{\Omega} u^{2} dx = u \nabla u \lvert_{\Omega} - \int_{\Omega} \lvert \nabla u \rvert^{2} dx$$ If you think about what we are doing when we compute the [first variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_variation), then this approach makes sense. However, I'm not an expert in this field and hopefully someone else can give you a more thorough answer.

Comment: Do you distinguish between a functional and an energy functional?

Comment: Existence does not even follow for ODE, there are some ODEs that do and can not have an associated Lagrangian (and therefore energy functional). This means they are not the Euler-Lagrange equation(s) of some energy functional. Uniqueness is also not given, since you can always add a Null-Lagrangian (and therefore have multiple energy functionals).

Comment: @mattos Forgive me for being stupid, I'm still not quite clear why this approach makes sense after thinking about the process of computing the first variation. The first variation of the functional $I=\int_\Omega L(x,u(x),\nabla u(x)) d x$ (where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $u: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, and $L$ is the Lagrangian) is calculated as follows: \begin{align} &\frac{d}{dt} \int_\Omega L(x,u+t \phi,\nabla u+t \nabla \phi) dx|_{t=0} \\ =&\int_\Omega L_u(x,u,\nabla u) \phi+L_p(x,u,\nabla u)\cdot \nabla \phi dx \\=&\int_\Omega [L_u(x,u,\nabla u)-div L_p(x,u,\nabla u)]\phi dx \end{align}

Comment: @mattos where $L_p=(L_{p_1},...L_{p_n})$, $L_{p_i}=L_{\partial_{x_i}u}$, and $\phi\in C_0^1(\Omega)$ is any test function. Conversely, if we multiply the E-L equation \begin{equation} L_u(x,u,\nabla u)-div L_p(x,u,\nabla u)=0 \end{equation} by $u$ and integrate it by parts in $\Omega$, we get the formula in the second line in my last comment, except that $\phi$ is replaced by $u$ and the boundary integration term (i.e. $\int_{\partial \Omega}$) is not omitted. Is that what your approach is basically doing?

Comment: @Qmechanic I didn't distinguish them in this question. Could you please tell me the difference? Thank you very much.

Comment: @F.Conrad Thank you very much!

Comment: [This Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3726398/techniques-for-constructing-an-energy-functional-from-a-system-of-pdes) are surely relevant.